# How to open port 8080 on external interface?

Tags: firewall

I am running a server on port 8080, which I can access fine as localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080.

However, assuming my IP address is 192.168.1.15, how can I access the port using 192.168.1.15:8080?

The Mac firewall is disabled in System Preferences.

Comment: If you're behind a router you may have to forward your port.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't even reach it from another system that's w/in my lan zone, i.e. within same 192.168.1.x address space, including my own system.  In my browser I type 127.0.0.1:8080 and it's fine, but 192.168.1.15:8080 can't connect to server